# rgb2pct.py increases size of file 20 fold!

Tags: raster, gdal, convert, geotiff-tiff, file-formats

I wanted to reduce the number of bands of a tif file from 3 to 1...

I used this command

```
rgb2pct.py -n 256 fnp_braunschweig.tif fnp_bs.tif
```

and it increased the size from 31mb to 778mb

I actually want to decrease the size of the file.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output Tiff is likely not using compression, hence the larger file size. Use the `gdal_translate` command, something along the lines of this:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -b N fnp_braunschweig.tif fnp_bs.tif
```

where `N` is the band number you want to keep. The options for compression are NONE, LZW, PACKBITS, JPEG, CCITTRLE, CCITTFAX3, CCITTFAX4, DEFLATE.

Comment: Especially note the -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" and -co "PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR" if appropriate.  Use gdalinfo to determine what the compression settings of the original tiff were and use creation options from http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html appropriately.

Comment: thanks. how can I compress three bands into one? I don´t want to pick either red,green, or blue, I just want to compress them into one.